# Python - Override parent class attribute without instantiation

Tags: python, oop, inheritance, overriding, subclass

How do I go about overriding a parent class attribute in a child class ***without using object instances of either class?*** Coming from the world of Java/C++ and their strict structural designs, I'm finding myself challenged by Python's way of doing things. I'd like to stay relatively static.

**Example:**

```
from urllib.parse import urljoin

class base:
    host = "/host/"
    path = "Override this in child classes"
    url = urljoin(host, path)

class config(base):
    path = "config"

    @classmethod
    def print_url(cls):
        print(cls.url) # Currently prints "/host/Override this in child classes"
                       # Would like to print "/host/config" instead

class log(base):
    path = "log"

    @classmethod
    def print_url(cls):
        print(cls.url) # Currently prints "/host/Override this in child classes"
                       # Would like to print "/host/log" instead
```

**Desired Usage**:

```
>>> config.print_url()
/host/config

>>> log.print_url()
/host/log
```

I'd like the `config.path` and `log.path` attributes to override `base.path`. This is so I can use `url = urljoin(host, path)` once and for all in the `base` class (and avoid having to copy/paste that same attribute/calculation in every single derived class).

I can't figure out how to accomplish this without constructing objects (which I'm hoping to avoid). Anyone have any advice? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Python classes are objects too. You can treat them as such.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The child `path` attributes do override `base.path`. What you don't override is the `url` attribute. That gets computed once when the body of `base` is run to create the class object.

You have a couple of options going forward. Either way you need to make `url` compute dynamically, either every time it's accessed, or at least once per child class.

The simplest way is to make `url` into a `classmethod`:

```
class base:
    host = "/host/"
    path = "Override this in child classes"

    @classmethod
    def url(cls):
        return urljoin(cls.host, cls.path)

    @classmethod
    def print_url(cls):
        print(cls.url())

class config(base):
    path = "config"

class log(base):
    path = "log"
```

Notice that you're referring to the actual classe's `host` and `path` on the fly now. You also only need one `print_url` method in `base` instead of a different one in each class.

Another option is to give `base`, and therefore all its children, a metaclass with `url` as a `property`:

```
class url_meta(type):
    @property
    def url(cls):
        return urljoin(cls.host, cls.path)

class base(metaclass=url_meta):
    host = "/host/"
    path = "Override this in child classes"

    @classmethod
    def print_url(cls):
        print(cls.url)

class config(base):
    path = "config"

class log(base):
    path = "log"
```

This works because python classes are objects too. You can define a `property` in the class of a class (the metaclass), and it will behave as any `property` does with respect to an instance. Just this time the instance is a class itself.

A third option is to make sure that `url` is defined statically but correctly in each child. The [`__init_subclass__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__init_subclass__) method allows you to do that very conveniently directly from `base`:

```
class base:
    host = "/host/"
    path = "Override this in child classes"
    url = urljoin(host, path)

    @classmethod
    def __init_subclass__(cls):
        cls.url = urljoin(cls.host, cls.path)

    @classmethod
    def print_url(cls):
        print(cls.url)

class config(base):
    path = "config"

class log(base):
    path = "log"
```

You can accomplish the same thing with a metaclass as well:

```
class url_meta2(type):
    def __init__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        cls.url = urljoin(cls.host, cls.path)

class base(metaclass=url_meta2):
    host = "/host/"
    path = "Override this in child classes"

    @classmethod
    def print_url(cls):
        print(cls.url)

class config(base):
    path = "config"

class log(base):
    path = "log"
```

Comment: @Mad_Physicist Thank you so much for the detailed answer, this was exactly what I was looking for!! I had no idea of the existence of metaclasses or __init_subclass__, I'm going to add these to my toolbelt now!